# How to handle multiple requests with the help of one function in AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter-3

view

```
<?php 
for(condition)
{
?>
<input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php echo $data1->id; ?>">
<a href="#" name="like" id="bttHello" >Like&nbsp;<i class="far fa-thumbs-up icon-4x text-default"></i></a>
<?php 
}
?>
```

AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$ (document) .ready(function() {
      $('[name="like"]') .click (function() {
      var pid = $('[name="pid"]').val();
      alert(pid);
});
});
</script>
```

**Expected Result:-**
If I click on like anchor tag it should show me different id for different posts and I don't want to reload my page.

**Actual Result:-**
It is showing me the first id when I click on different like tags of different posts.

I am new to AJAX.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have not given a different id to the input type name anchor tag.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `ajax` and `codeigniter`, please update your tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

view

```
<?php 
for($i=0;$i<count($data1);$i++)
{
?>
<input type="hidden" name="pid#<?=$i?>" value="<?php echo $data1->id; ?>">
<a href="#" name="like#<?=$i?>" id="bttHello" >Like&nbsp;<i class="far fa-thumbs-up icon-4x text-default"></i></a>
<?php 
}
?>
```

AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$ (document) .ready(function() {
      $('[name="like"]') .click (function() {
      $name = $(this).split("#");

      var pid = $('pid'+$name[1]).val();
      alert(pid);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Now i know where was the problem.

Comment: @jarvis okay if your problem is solved please accept the answer and also rate those which helped you out.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> $ (document) .ready(function() { $('[name="like"]').click(function () { var input = $($(this).siblings("input")[0]); // get the input element var value = input.val(); //value of the input // alert(value); $.ajax ({ type : 'POST', data:{value :value}, url:'<?php echo base_url('blog/like') ?>' }); }); }); </script> Here, i am not receiving any request in my controller. help me.

Comment: please accept this answer and ask a new question if you have a different problem now share the link.

Comment: @jarvis and also share the full code in proper format in new question so that we can understand. It is difficult to understand in comments without proper format and full code.

Answer (score 0):

you place the `input` and `a` inside the `div` and then get the `a`'s sibling which is the `input`

```
<?php

for (condition) {
?>
  <div>
    //Your input and a tag here
  </div>
<?php   } 
?>


<script>

$('[name="like"]').click(function () {
   var input = $($(this).siblings("input")[0]); // get the input element
   var value = input.val(); //value of the input
   alert(value);
});
</script>
```

Comment: var input = $($(this).find("input")[0]);

will also give the same result.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli: no, it won't. `find()` search for child elements, not siblings

Comment: but when in case of div ($this) it will only search within that div. I have done it before.

Comment: In that case, you detect the click of the `div`: `$('div').on('click', 'a', function(){ var input = $(this).find('input')[0]; })`. This case `$(this)` refers to the `div` element, then you can search for its child element. My solution detects event of `a` element, `$(this)` then refers to `a` element, that why I have to search for siblings.

Comment: okay, but he is not using any div. so the sibling will not work.

Comment: That why my answer tells OP to put the `input` and `a` inside a `div` while doing the loop. Please reread my answer again

Comment: @catcon
Now i want to call a function which is inside a controller with the value that i got.
like this ------------   $this->controller_name->function_name(value);

Comment: So you want to pass that value to PHP? You have to create a HTTP Get or Post request to your server. Then you can get the value using PHP $_GET or $_POST

Comment: @catcon 
<script type="text/javascript">
 $ (document) .ready(function() {
 $('[name="like"]').click(function () {
 var input = $($(this).siblings("input")[0]); // get the input element 
var value = input.val(); //value of the input 
// alert(value); 
$.ajax ({ type : 'POST', data:{value :value}, 
url:'<?php echo base_url('blog/like') ?>' 
}); }); }); 
</script> 
Here, i am not receiving any request in my controller. help me

Answer (score 0):

You are setting same `name for all the input`.

If you don't need `input` field as hidden then you can use `attribute` to set and get the value of your post.

```
<?php 
for(condition)
{
?>
<input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php echo $data1->id; ?>">
<a href="#" name="like" data-pid="<?php echo $data1->id; ?>" class="select_pid" id="bttHello" >Like&nbsp;<i class="far fa-thumbs-up icon-4x text-default"></i></a>
<?php 
}
?>
```

You can use class name to access the attribute of anchor tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '.select_id', function(){
    var pid = $(this).attr('data-pid');
    alert(pid);
});
</script>
```